# If a large magnet is traveling through space and it is suddenly shielded at it's source what happens to the part of the field already past the source?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I know that whenever a field forms it travels *to* area it travels at the speed of light, but once it's already there, what would happen to the edge of the field if it were instantly shielded at it's source, or at the very least shielded quickly enough a so the field could not return quickly enough? would it dissipate? would it pull back to it's source at the speed of light, lingering for a microscopic delay? what would it do?

Comment: A magnetic field at its own can’t travel through space. Futhermore an electric field can’t do so. Only the emission of photons or electromagnetic radiation is possible. The presumption of your question is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine the ripples on a pond after you threw a rock into the water. Now after the ripples have moved some distance, you put down a hollow cylinder at the source of the circular waves. (Which of course is the point your rock landed in).

What happens to the waves? Are they going to move back to the source? I guess your intuition is good enough to know that that's not the case. While the source of the oscilation is now shielded by the cylinder, the waves that are already moving on the surface on the pond remain unaffected. They just move on like nothing happened.
It's the same with any classical physical field such as the magnetic or electric field.

Comment: You can deform an electric or a magnetic field from a source. But you can’t cut such fields. Another question is the emission of EM radiation. But this happens in quanta and once emitted there is no more a connection to the source.

Comment: I think this is wrong. magnetic and electric fields  from a source, are not radiating like ripples on a pond. The classical sollution of the  energy they carry is carried by the source  whereas the ripples in the pond are independent. The question is not about an antenna and electromagnetic waves

Comment: The placement of the shield can be thought of as a step function. The act of the magnetic source "disappearing" is similar to accelerating a charge, and sufficient to radiate a field, albeit a pulse instead of a wave.

Comment: @annav You're absolutely right. It was my impression that (because of the way he phrased the question) was talking about EM fields and decided to give him an analogy. This should still hold true though for a simple magnetic field, because the act of shielding the field radiates a field, just like kthaxt describes.

Comment: I was talking about a ordinary(abeit very large magnetic field)...I was wondering how the field went away, and if it went away at the speed of light, now I'm confused...

Answer (score 0):

Classical electric and magnetic fields exist only when probed with test charges , otherwise they are a mathematical construct that can describe the behavior of charges and magnets to a great accuracy.

Let us take an analogous simpler  problem, a charged sphere , which has a potential of ~1/r and an electric field proportional to 1/r^2 . What happens to the electric field if you slide in front of it  at a distance d a metal plate?

You have changed the boundary conditions of the problem, which now becomes a solution with a charged sphere reflected from a conducting plane. [In page three of this link](http://web.hep.uiuc.edu/home/serrede/P435/Lecture_Notes/P435_Lect_06.pdf) there is a solution with specific boundaries, the method of images. Behind the conducting grounded plane there will no longer be an electric field. But the solution in front of the grounded conductor will look like  the solution of  two  spheres in the whole space.

How fast will the electric field disappear ? as fast as you move the conducting plane into position, but there will be distortions, because the boundary conditions will be continually changing and a time dependent solution must be searched for.

If you put a test charge while you are pushing the conducting plane in place it will measure less and less  electric field until it is in full place, when it will measure zero for all the space behind .

Magnetic fields are more complicated because they cannot be really isolated but if a material existed, the same logic would apply.

Now you put the extra hypothesis of a moving source,which will only complicate the mathematics, the physics is the same. The field will disappear as the boundary conditions change because it is a mathematical construct dependent on the source.

Comment: When you say the field will disappear as fast as the plate is positioned,  appears instantly? (Let's say it's made out of plasma traveling at relativistic speeds) will the field disappear at the speed of light?

Comment: How fast the change will happen  will be a solution to  complicated mathematical equations with the boundary conditions,  which will of course depend on the speed of light ( inherent in any electromagnetic effects) but also include the speed  of translation of the barriere  in creating the obstruction

Comment: so in other words the field will be bent and redirected to behind the shield getting pushed/pulled away at approximately the speed of light/slower based on mathematical models?